# What kind of color code is this?

Tags: colors

I'm using a [software](http://zoxel.blogspot.it/) which exports among others color codes like the following

```
4278190335
2358853119
656213503
4244695807
545395711
2448883199
7991807
```

I've never seen such codes before, what kind of color code is this?
*Is this even a valid color code?* since these are from 7 to 10 digit codes - maybe there are color codes with less or more digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably just the raw decimal color. 4278190335 in hex is FF 00 00 FF. The last FF is the alpha channel. Each group of 2 digits before corresponds to Red Green and Blue levels. 
Convert them all to hex and break them into pairs of digits.

Comment: Yep, that's it ;) Thanks! (but it was [color][alpha] in this case :p)